# Harm/Damage/Ruin/Spoil image

Tags: word-usage, american-english

If someone does something that is not good for someone's image what is a natural way to describe that?

> He ruined my image.
>
> He spoiled my image.
>
> He damaged my image.
>
> He harmed my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all of these are good choices (with **ruined** and **damaged** being the two most natural).

> Ruined

In addition to a "downgrading" of someone's image, this also implies that the image is now more on the "bad" than the "good" side. I wouldn't necessarily use this if the image went from "superb" to "good".

> Spoiled

This has a connotation that the person who's image is being damaged, had created the image sort of as a farce. For example, imagine someone had been lying and saying that they had a very wealthy family, where connected well politically, and had a very noble personality (when in reality they were just a normal person with an indifferent personality). If someone else exposed this person as lying, then Person 2 spoiled Person 1's image.

It has the sense that the image being damaged was inflated to begin with.

> Damage

A pretty common way to refer to the scenario you are describing. It generally has the sense that the damage only a took down a portion of someone's image. So if you want to emphasize that the damage was large, you would add intensity words like "really damaged", "severely damaged", or "damaged ... forever."

> Harmed

This meaning to me implies a less sever consequence than any of the above.

Comment: Can "ruin" be used in the second scenario as well?

Comment: I would say yes